# problemas con galería lightbox

Tags: php

Necesito hacer una galería con dos niveles de profundidad, es decir que muestre unas miniaturas de un directorio, y que al hacer link en una miniatura muestre imágenes de otro directorio, agrandando las imágenes. Intenté hacerlo con lightbox con lo poco que sé de este script, pero no conseguí realizarlo.
Agradezco cualquier sugerencia. Muchas gracias.

```html
<!--CREACION DE ARRAY CON IMAGENES-->
        <?php
        $pathAlbum = "img/";
        $albumArray=Array();
        foreach(glob($pathAlbum . '*.jpg') as $imageAlbum) {
            $albumArray[]=$imageAlbum;
        }    
        for($a = 1; $a <= count($albumArray); $a++):
        ?>
        
        <!--MINIATURAS CON VINCULOS-->
        <section id="gallery">
            <section class="item">
                <a href="#img<?php echo $a-1; ?>">
                    <?php
                    echo '<img src = "' . $albumArray[$a-1] . '">';
                    ?>
                </a>
            </section>
        </section>
        
        <!--GALERIA LIGHTBOX-->
        <div class="lightbox" id="img<?php echo $a-1; ?>">
            <div class="box">
                <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
                <p class="title">Galeria</p>
                <!--imágenes de otro directorio-->
                <div class="content">
                    <?php
                    $path = "img/0/";
                    foreach(glob($path . '*.jpg') as $image) { 
                        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">'."<br/>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <!--navegación-->
                <a class="prev" href="#img<?php echo ($a-1)-1; ?>">Previous</a>
                <a class="next" href="#img<?php echo ($a-1)+1; ?>">Next</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

```css
#gallery {
    width:660px;
    margin:100px auto;
    }

#gallery .item {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px;
    }

.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }

.lightbox:target {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    }

.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    min-width:500px;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #777777; 
    }

.lightbox .title {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
    font-size:22px;
    }

.lightbox .content {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }

.lightbox .content .desc {
    z-index:99;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 4px 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }   

.lightbox .content:hover .desc  {
    opacity:1;
    }

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#858585;
    }

.prev {
    float:left;
    }

.next, .close {
    float:right;
    }

    .clear {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        }
```

Comment: Que problema tienes?

Comment: Las imágenes que saco de otro directorio al hacer click en una miniatura aparecen juntas, algunas no se ven y no puedo navegar entre ellas.